# Using injected HttpClient from HttpClientFactory out of scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Consider this code

```
public class ScopedService {
    public readonly HttpClient client;
    public readonly MyHostedService hostedService;

    public ScopedService(HttpClient client, MyHostedService hostedService) {
        this.client = client;
        this.hostedService = hostedService;
    }

    public void LongAsyncOperationWeDontWantToWaitFor()
    {
        var httpTask = client.GetAsync("...");
        hostedService.SaveTaskForProcessSometimeInTheFuture(httpTask);
    }
}
```

I have a scoped service which makes an http call. I want the scope to close before the http call completes. If I created and disposed `httpClient` manually, then I'd do it out of scope myself. But since in this case the client is Dependency Injected, I have no control over when it's going to be disposed. Can there be a situation, that the context won't be able to close until the injected `httpClient` is disposed?

Comment: Why do you care about the lifecycle of the `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

You could inject IHttpClientFactory and use it to create the HttpClient when you need it.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing as injecting HttpClient?

Comment: No, the factory is a singleton, and it means you get to create the client just when you need it, potentially out of the request scope.

Comment: Dispose on HttpClient created from the HttpClientFactory is a no-op as well, so no need to worry about disposing it.